How can i filter rows by one condition (id) which are repeated in two days
i have a df, which containing 4 columns:

microbiological data (mo),
sample_date,
and patient id (pid_code),
id (for each rows).

Its looks like this:



id
mo
sample_date
pid_code




1
Staphylococcus epidermidis
2019-12-13
120


2
Staphylococcus epidermidis
2019-12-14
120


3
Staphylococcus capitis
2020-01-13
131


4
Staphylococcus hominis
2021-11-14
155


5
Staphylococcus hominis
2021-11-17
155


6
Micrococcus luteus
2023-06-06
133


7
Micrococcus luteus
2023-06-07
133



i want to filter those rows where the pid_code and mo is same, and repeated in 2 days.
So i want to get back these rows.



id
mo
sample_date
pid_code




1
Staphylococcus epidermidis
2019-12-13
120


2
Staphylococcus epidermidis
2019-12-14
120


6
Micrococcus luteus
2023-06-06
133


7
Micrococcus luteus
2023-06-07
133



Do you have something advise?
Thanks

Here is a dplyr solution:
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  filter(any(abs(difftime(sample_date, lag(sample_date), units = "days")) <= 2), .by=c(mo, pid_code))

              id          mo sample_date pid_code
1 Staphylococcus epidermidis  2019-12-13      120
2 Staphylococcus epidermidis  2019-12-14      120
6    Micrococcus      luteus  2023-06-06      133
7    Micrococcus      luteus  2023-06-07      133


Despite the conditions, for some reason it included a repetition 1 month later. Maybe I should have rearranged the df?

Suppose your data frame is named df. Now Convert sample_date to Date:
df$sample_date <- as.Date(df$sample_date)

Arrange the data frame by pid_code, mo, and sample_date:
df <- df %>%
  arrange(pid_code, mo, sample_date)

Calculate the time difference between consecutive rows within the same group:
df <- df %>%
  group_by(pid_code, mo) %>%
  mutate(time_diff = sample_date - lag(sample_date)) %>%
  ungroup()

Filter rows where the time difference is less than or equal to 2:
filtered_df <- df %>%
  filter(as.numeric(time_diff) <= 2) %>%
  select(-time_diff)


Within the AMR package you can run first_isolate() and select your episode days are 2
https://msberends.github.io/AMR/reference/first_isolate.html
You would need to transform your mo column to an organism column recognisable by the package, but that's easy
df$organism<- as.mo(df$mo)

I make it into a different column so I keep the original in case in the conversion it turns to something weird (which happens rarely).
